# Accelerated ion beam current

Tags: electrostatics, electrons, potential, ions

If an electron gun creates a $10\space mA$ electron beam and each electron collides with a gas atom and creates an ion through impact ionization, can the ions then be accelerated with a separate negative voltage grid that is powered by a lower current capacity source but still maintains a $10\space mA$ current?

Basically, in the figure below - what is the maximum ion current accelerated by the $30kV$ grid?

[image: circuit]

(The gas pressure would be $10^{-5}$ Tor.)

**Clarification**: Is the ion current directly proportional to the current capacity of the 30kV grid?

Comment: Is this an actual device, or a design idea?

Comment: @rob, It's a design idea. Your thoughts?

Comment: My guess is that if the gas is dense enough to act like a fluid, which you've suggested with your little cloud, then intra-fluid collisions will prevent any acceleration and you'll make a discharge tube. With a vacuum system to keep the gas at plasma densities, you might get some ions out.  Thirty kilovolts is nontrivial. You should study some existing designs. Older documents sometimes assume less prior knowledge; [Ramsey](http://www.oxfordscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780198520214.001.0001/acprof-9780198520214) (very active midcentury, Nobel 1984-ish) is a good author to look for.

Comment: @rob, thank you for the references, I'll look into those! As a side note I didn't intend the cloud to represent a high density of gas, only that gas was present; the operating pressure is probably somewhere in the $10^{-5}$ Tor range.

Comment: [Electron Beam Ion Sources](http://www-eng.lbl.gov/~dleitner/USPAS_2016_Fundamental_Of_Ion_Sources/4_Thursday_PM_EBIT.pdf)

Comment: maybe one reason that this question (good question) didn't receive enough attention is because it is unclear. I'm having trouble with the mechanism of how the ion charges are accelerated. In addition, I think the reason why you are proposing this design is also useful and relevant information.

Comment: @psitae, the ions generated (created through impact ionization) between the grounded grid on the left and the negative grid on the right should be accelerated by the grid on the right. The question is, is the ion current limited by the available current of the grid on the right side (30kV).

Comment: I don't think you have the freedom to decide how much current is established in the final electrode (right most). It is decided by the electron beam (or the ion beam).